# the jquery method works fine but when made as a function not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-slide-effects

my Jquery code works fine if i dont keep the code inside function and call it but as a function not working

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input:radio").change(function(){
        checkResult();
        });
    });
        function checkResult()
        {
        $this=$(this).parent("div.QA");
        $this.slideUp();
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

because `this` inside the function does not refer to the clicked `radio` element, since you are writing it as a separate function pass the clicked element as a parameter

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio").change(function(){
        checkResult(this);
    });
});
function checkResult(el) {
    var $this = $(el).parent("div.QA");
    $this.slideUp();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the function name - checkResult as callback, so that `this` will refer to the changed element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio").change(checkResult);
});
function checkResult()
{
    $this=$(this).parent("div.QA");
    $this.slideUp();
}
```